# Poner switch dentro de un método

Tags: c#

Trabajo con C# VS 2019

Tengo el siguiente método que debe devolver un valor decimal

```
private decimal ObtenerMultiplicador(int value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case 1:
                return 10M;
            //break;
            case 2:
                return 100M;
            //break;
            case 3:
                return 1000M;
            //break;
            case 4:
                return 10000M;
            //break;
            case 5:
                return 100000M;
            //break;
            case 6:
                return 1000000M;
                //break;
                //default:
                //    break;
        }
    }
```

El error que obtengo en la implementación es: "No todas las rutas devuelven resultado".

Comment: Pedrito, hermano, lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Para eliminar ese error debes descomentar la linea  `//default:` y logicamente deberas incluir una linea `return xxxxxM;` que retorne un valor decimal, lo que depende de la logica que tenga tu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso es porque si el número es mayor a 6 la función no sabe que decimal regresar, porque si o si debes regresar un decimal, así que solo debes devolver algún valor en el default, además de quitar los break.

Que pasa si el número es mayor a 6?, yo podría decir que como es mayor a 6 no se debe hacer conversión y regresar el mismo número o bien regresar un 0, eso es lo que debes dejar en el default.

```
private decimal ObtenerMultiplicador(int value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case 1:
            return 10M;

        case 2:
            return 100M;

        case 3:
            return 1000M;

        case 4:
            return 10000M;

        case 5:
            return 100000M;

        case 6:
            return 1000000M;

        default:
            return 0; // o bien return value;
    }
}
```

Ahora bien, también puedes omitir el uso de switch e implementar la función de otra forma, por ejemplo:

```
    private decimal ObtenerMultiplicador(int value)
    {
        string s = "1" + new string('0', value);/*esto crea una cadena que empieza con 1 y le agrega una nueva cadena que estará compuesta por tantos ceros como se espcifique en la variable value*/
        return decimal.Parse(s);//esto convertirá dicha cadena en un decimal y la regresará
    }
```

Y así todo lo del switch se hace en dos líneas de código, además soportará cualquier valor, si pasas un 7 no importará no tendrás que hacer otro case, ahora bien puedes añadir una validación por si la conversión solo se permite hasta 6 algo como

```
private decimal ObtenerMultiplicador(int value)
{
    if(value > 6)
       return 0;//o bien return value;

    string s = "1" + new string('0', value);
    return decimal.Parse(s);
}
```